# Using Facebook from iOS 5 with FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I want to use the FacebookSDK to enable users of my iOS 5 app to post stuff from my app on their Facebook pages. So I gathered that I need to use the FacebookSDK provided by Facebook for this. To use the FacebookSDK I need an app id. However, my company only has a Facebook page as it seems. And apparently I cannot create an app id with a Facebook page.

Is this correct?
If yes, how can I create an app ID? I don't want to link the app to individual people, but to my company's product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your company should have an account (not a page) on facebook in order to assign an application id to it.

Just go on to : https://developers.facebook.com/ .

Login with your company account, click the **Apps** tab and than click **Create New App**